# How to fix this order by sql consult? How to change dimension label from pie chart metabase?

Tags: sql, date, metabase

I've been trying to build a pie chart in a metabase question, to put into my dashboard. 
I have player_id and updated_at columns, and I executed a consult to return the number of updated_at by day. I done this with a problem, I can't use order by, I don't know why but this isn't working. So, I would like to know where I am erring.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT date(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS d, count(DISTINCT player_id) AS c FROM matchmaking_stats_summary WHERE updated_at between '2020-02-01 00:00:00' and '2020-02-01 23:59:59' union 
SELECT date(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS d, count(DISTINCT player_id) AS c FROM matchmaking_stats_summary WHERE updated_at between '2020-02-02 00:00:00' and '2020-02-02 23:59:59' union
SELECT date(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS d, count(DISTINCT player_id) AS c FROM matchmaking_stats_summary WHERE updated_at between '2020-02-03 00:00:00' and '2020-02-03 23:59:59' union
SELECT date(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS d, count(DISTINCT player_id) AS c FROM matchmaking_stats_summary WHERE updated_at between '2020-02-04 00:00:00' and '2020-02-04 23:59:59' union
SELECT date(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS d, count(DISTINCT player_id) AS c FROM matchmaking_stats_summary WHERE updated_at between '2020-02-05 00:00:00' and '2020-02-05 23:59:59' 
) AS x
ORDER BY d asc
```

The column updated_at type is timestamp. A value example is: 2020-02-01 00:47:32
And another question is why I can't set the Dimession and Meassure in Metabase, I would like to set Dimession label to respective date interval and the count number in Meassure label. Is it possible?

[image: can I put the date interval on dimension label?] 
Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: you dont need these unions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `group by`?

```
SELECT date(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS d, 
       count(DISTINCT player_id) AS c
FROM matchmaking_stats_summary
WHERE updated_at >= '2020-02-01 00:00:00' and 
      updated_at < '2020-02-06 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY date(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been making changes in my sql code, and I finally reach a way to handle date interval and count of players as pie chart metabase dimension and meassure.

```
select date(updated_at), count(DISTINCT updated_at) as jogadores
    from matchmaking_stats_summary
        group by date(updated_at)
        order by date(updated_at) asc;
```

Thank you a lot.